# Discord Bot Error - cannot read property of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

This is the code:

```js
const client = require("../bot");
const { Collection } = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")
const config = require("../config.js")
let prefix = config.prefix

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.komutlar = new Collection();
  client.aliases = new Collection();
  fs.readdir("./komutlar/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) 
      console.error(err);

    files.forEach(f => {
      let props = require(`../komutlar/${f}`);
      client.komutlar.set(props.help.name, props);
      props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
        client.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This is the error:

[image]

I think the source of the error is the mixing of v13 or v14 versions.

Comment: For future reference, please copy/paste the error message as text in to the question, not an image

Comment: Regarding the error, it's because `props.help` is undefined. There's not enough information in the question to tell you why that is, but I'd suggest you check the code in whatever is referenced by ``../komutlar/${f}``

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you have a chance to help from discord or anydesk? I don't know much about these issues and I'm trying to transfer a project to my own

Comment: can you update your question with file structure?

Answer (score -1):

As I guess that you should have wrong folder access.

`fs.readdir("./komutlar/", (err, files) => {`

Reading files from "./komutlar" but

```
 let props = require(`../komutlar/${f}`);
```

access it from '../komutlar' you can change it into. If not working I would like to know how your folder directory looks like

```
const client = require("../bot");
const { Collection } = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")
const config = require("../config.js")
let prefix = config.prefix

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.komutlar = new Collection();
  client.aliases = new Collection();
  fs.readdir("./komutlar/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) 
      console.error(err);

    files.forEach(f => {
      let props = require(`./komutlar/${f}`);
      client.komutlar.set(props.help.name, props);
      props.conf.aliases.forEach(alias => {
        client.aliases.set(alias, props.help.name);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: https://hastebin.com/share/izivusaroj.php

Comment: What is folder directory look like . It can’t found that file. Can contact me in discord:@hellcatvn